# org.springframework.data.relational 404 JHiphipster

Tags: spring, jhipster

I created a microservice application using JHipster. The only issue I am having is that this following dependency is not found.

```
  org.springframework.data.relational
```

to be more specific

```
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcProperties;
```

with the URL in the error

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/experimental/spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc/0.1.0.M1/spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc-0.1.0.M1.pom

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:${spring_boot_starter_data_r2dbc_version}"
```

gradle.properties

```
spring_boot_starter_data_r2dbc_version=0.1.0.
```

I would just like to ask if anyone had a similar issue issue before I create a bug ticket.

This can be easily replicated using the yeoman `yo` command.

Comment: Have the same problem, seems like spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I found the reason:

In latest version Release 6.10.5 JHipster still used the experimental artifact of spring boot, which is not experimental anymore and therefore moved to the official spring boot groupid in the maven repository. Unfortunately changing this is not enough, as jhipster is using spring boot 2.2.7 and spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc is only available since 2.3.
The solution for me is to use the beta release of jhipster 7, where they moved to Spring boot 2.3.

Available here:
https://www.jhipster.tech/2020/12/21/jhipster-release-7.0.0-beta.0.html
or with:

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster@beta
```